# Delete rows in Excel based on duplicates in a single Column

Tags: vba, excel

I need to delete an entire row based on duplicates in a specified column, I need to delete all but the first occurrence.

I have A to N Columns and unknown rows as the last row number changes with day to day activity. N has the value that is evaluated for the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
Sub Remove_Duplicates()
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("A1:N" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row).RemoveDuplicates 
Columns:=14, Header:=xlYes
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting compile error: Expected: expression... This row becomes red in color "Columns:=14, Header:=xlYes"

Comment: You can try selecting your columns and remove duplicates manually. Give it a try

Comment: ActiveSheet.Range("A:N").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=14, Header:=xlNo

Above vb code helped me to remove duplicate